# Not understanding difference in computational complexity between different algorithms

Tags: python, algorithm, performance, time-complexity

I am currently doing some coding problems on leetcode.com and am stumped by the difference in computational time between two algorithms that output the same result.

The problem:
Given a string array words, find the maximum value of length(word[i]) * length(word[j]) where the two words do not share common letters. You may assume that each word will contain only lower case letters. If no such two words exist, return 0.

At a bare minimum, one needs to compare every combination of pairs of strings in order to compute the answer. I realize bitwise is much faster/more efficient, but I am choosing to ignore it for the sake of this question.

You can find the test case word list I am using at the bottom of this post.

Algorithm 1:

```
curr_max=0
for i in range(0,len(words)):
    for j in range(0,len(words)):
        if i<j:
            curr_word=set(words[i])
            other_word=words[j]
            for char in curr_word:
                if char in other_word:
                    break
            else:
                curr_max=max(curr_max,len(words[i])*len(other_word))
print(curr_max)
```

This algorithm essentially is a nested for loop that compares every possible combination of words, and would include double counts and counts against itself if not for the "if i

Algorithm 2:

```
curr_max = 0
while words:
    curr_word = set(words[0])
    curr_len = len(words[0])
    words = words[1:]
    for word in words:
        for char in curr_word:
            if char in word:
                break
        else:
            curr_max = max(curr_max, curr_len*len(word))
print(curr_max)
```

This algorithm essentially compares the first word in the list to all the others, then deletes it from the list and repeats the process. It takes approximately 0.02 seconds, making it about 4 times faster. I am having a hard time understanding why exactly the difference is so large. Thanks in advance for all the help!

The input I am using to compare the times is this:

```
words=["eedfdddadbcc","acdadecebafaebaec","dfde","ececbefe","bbafebbeccbddddbd","eafeffddbbbf","cbd","abadeaddfbcfbadb","ffdcacaebbeaa","fbadcfeede","bdcefdbfec","bbadfccdfebefd","dbefdfabededb","cbbccdecfbbe","abaeeecdbecebafedbfee","fbefbdfc","fffafb","bfadbdefbfedbddff","cbccbfdadbfe","bacaafecbbfaae","fcbffdbefcfbccd","fefaadfaaafdfbdaff","ecabaff","ccbdefcdcfac","bbbfafbffcefbc","edecefa","bcdfbcebabae","aaefecfcbbccfaeeaf","beaabaaeaebef","adfac","acedfdabccebc","efbfbef","bfccadbcbcfcdabfa","ffcaddbcf","dfae","ccadeeebeaabddebcadec","babaa","ebbdbaabddfdddad","fafaddbaebdaa","eeeeddadedfe","effbca","abcddfa","cbadcfeffeaaeecbbfe","ceaabcfaaaefeeadf","acecadddde","ece","dc","bfafdefbbdafacdcfb","fbdcad","dbaaffcdbcbdea","baaee","bebed","beaedceceaa","eacbcfdbcefbaddffcac","acddaedacfeedffad","efebff","efcbf","cdfffffaacfacafb","adacaceea","fceeffededbcfbfaaf","eafaeffcbfde","debadcddbdbabefdbe","ef","eeeeabfbaabddaecb","eeadcdcdaacaabe","ebcbffdefafdcbcebec","eb","adedefbaabfcefbea","ddceabfddaaefcea","ddffb","fdadfac","de","cbcdcbddcdabeb","ccffeeafbbbf","ccba","dab","bbdbeefdbef","cbec","ffcbefdbfdacdbdbf","adfad","ceacdcbfbdbbaebbd","ecfeaefff","ddbbdaefddeebd","eeeee","abdadc","eafecdbdef","aeedaeeaebaaeecdd","dddeebcbdea","bcaadedacb","ebdeadddcafa","ecbdbcbfccbdffaef","fddcffbfffa","accbdcfcedeabeab","cfbbefbddcaeecfbfacc","efffdaacbafeecdad","aaadfa","efeccbabdefaf","defebaddaafdcd","ecebcaacdaccaddcfeee","fdbbfecaffeafaa","bafccdbea","caa","deedefdeccead","bbfbfeaeddacfacea","daaefbbcbcdbfbfdda","aceed","cfeadadadbcff","eaefcdca","cefebdbaafeabdbdeaafd","abec","aeececad","cfeabcbaeaebdbcaada","aac","ebabffeb","fa","cf","dcebedefc","dbaedceecf","ffebaedafccceb","faefbeacaddefbe","eeadbfabfbbbfaeffaeea","affdecaca","ccfdcbdefcdfaddbbeaed","bc","feafaaabaceade","bebdfbbad","eeacaefaddacac","fff","aeddcd","ccffbabbdfc","ecddbcdeecdfbbb","debdbcdcafdcd","cfaebaeddbbd","efdada","becdccaeffeedcadbdd","feedbacc","cbbeebcdad","bfdcbdfdbcceadded","cfdbfdddafadadddcba","bcedeaeeaac","ffdcfccffdfffaebf","afffceaaadbbedfdd","faaeebdfbfefddebed","eedafbddeeaaadcdeaccc","eeceadafa","ebcfaccabea","eebdbbedcaedcbdcfaba","ecfcadaebacbdfdccebe","cbbabdadaee","cfeea","dec","cfedcbaabbaef","aacdabcbf","dfdbacadbebeedcd","bccccfdcdfe","cfcacdbcdccddcadce","dafafeccfaccaadeabbf","eaffaaffefccde","bbfbddccfda","fbdbbbbfbe","eafbcafbdbead","edbcdcefdc","fe","aafdcabce","ddafedceddcdcbfbcafe","dabcafbcfafeeadbbbef","beeaacd","cadeabebdbcfbbdfe","ecfefbfbbfa","fedacafcc","bcdcefecbcebaeeccdbd","fefde","cafba","bdabeaabbdbbbccecebda","dfeaadbeaaeefdfbed","dbaecde","cfbdfffbdeeeeb","fc","decadcacfaabca","cebbdff","badabbddcfed","fcce","fedfadefcf","acfccfbfcda","debfc","bebafeaeffe","ceaefbbcefacbbacb","cebbaeb","cadedfdafecdfb","bfefdfbaceddfcbade","cefeefaeddafbbdcade","faceadcefbffadb","cfbacafae","dfbfadfdccedbcbeaae","dbbccdddaf","ebbcbcebdddcedcfdcfaa","ccedffbcdbaedfaeb","ccfeaceaaaaeee","faade","afaaacaecbffdbadcbcd","cebfbbefbbdabbbffea","cdaadba","bbefdcacaaadbbbdedec","adabfbebdb","fcfefadcbadaacbdcfdbb","adddadebfc","fb","ecfebaacbdabece","dabacfdecfe","eeeecc","eabbe","fcdffababd","aafdbbcfdecbccca","efebaaadfecccecaa","cffefdbf","bcbdd","eaaccdcfdbbbcf"]
```

***Updating OP to help the people assisting me with this question!***
I am now generating words using this:

```
words = [''.join([choice('abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz') for _ in range(randrange(2, 22))]) for _ in range(250)]
```

I am performing the first algorithm as so:

```
t1=time.time()
curr_max=0
for i in range(0,len(words)):
    for j in range(0,i):
        curr_word=set(words[i])
        other_word=words[j]
        for char in curr_word:
            if char in other_word:
                break
        else:
            curr_max=max(curr_max,len(words[i])*len(other_word))
print(curr_max)
t0=time.time()
print(t0-t1)
```

The results I am seeing are in the 0.1 seconds range.

The second algorithm I am using this:

```
t1=time.time()
curr_max = 0
while words:
    curr_word = set(words[0])
    curr_len = len(words[0])
    words = words[1:]
    for word in words:
        for char in curr_word:
            if char in word:
                break
        else:
            curr_max = max(curr_max, curr_len*len(word))
print(curr_max)
t0=time.time()
print(t0-t1)
```

I am seeing results in the 0.04-0.05 seconds range. Can anyone replicate this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Both algorithms look as if they the same amount of work. Both re-create the [`itertools.combinations()` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations). 
However, the first method re-creates the sets more often, and executes an additional n**2 of `i < j` tests (for n words)!

You are creating len(n) over 2 combinations, so n! / (n - 2)! (see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combination)), which is quite a lot less than n**2:

```
>>> import math
>>> n = 250
>>> math.factorial(n) / (math.factorial(2) * math.factorial(n - 2))
31125.0
>>> n ** 2
62500
>>> n ** 2 - (math.factorial(n) / (math.factorial(2) * math.factorial(n - 2)))
31375.0
```

So algorithm #1 executes more than twice as many loops as algorithm #2 for your specific case. As n increases, the product divided by the number of  combinations approaches 2, so it'll always do at least double the work.

Next, you create a set of `words[0]` in algorithm #2 only once, but you do it *for every inner loop* for algorithm #1:

```
# algorithm #1
for ...  # current word loop
    for ...   # other word loop
        set(words[i])

# algorithm #2
while    # current word loop
    set(words[0])
    for ...   # other word loop
```

It's those differences that causes it to be slower; creating (N over 2) sets vs. just N sets is probably costing you most of the performance here.

To make a proper comparison, you should use the [`timeit` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/timeit.html), which repeats tests many times, makes sure to use the most accurate clock for measuring time spent and disables the Python garbage collector (so it won't interfere). I've included a randomised word list, and for the destructive algorithm (your #2), I had to clone the list each time, for which I compensate by subtracting the time for the same number of bare list copies.

The script I ran:

```
from random import choice, randrange
from timeit import timeit

def naive_loop(words):
    curr_max=0
    for i in range(0,len(words)):
        for j in range(0,len(words)):
            if i<j:
                curr_word=set(words[i])
                other_word=words[j]
                for char in curr_word:
                    if char in other_word:
                        break
                else:
                    curr_max=max(curr_max,len(words[i])*len(other_word))
    return curr_max

def destructive_loop(words):
    curr_max = 0
    while words:
        curr_word = set(words[0])
        curr_len = len(words[0])
        words = words[1:]
        for word in words:
            for char in curr_word:
                if char in word:
                    break
            else:
                curr_max = max(curr_max, curr_len*len(word))
    return curr_max

def reduced_set_calls_loop(words):
    curr_max=0
    for i in range(0,len(words)):
        curr_word=set(words[i])
        for j in range(0,len(words)):
            if i<j:
                other_word=words[j]
                for char in curr_word:
                    if char in other_word:
                        break
                else:
                    curr_max=max(curr_max,len(words[i])*len(other_word))
    return curr_max


words = [''.join([choice('abcdef') for _ in range(randrange(2, 22))]) for _ in range(250)]
number = 100
print('Naive:', timeit('naive_loop(words)', 'from __main__ import naive_loop, words', number=number))
print('Destructive:',  # don't include time to copy a list
    timeit('destructive_loop(words[:])', 'from __main__ import destructive_loop, words', number=number) -
    timeit('words[:]', 'from __main__ import naive_loop, words', number=number))
print('Reduced set calls:', timeit('reduced_set_calls_loop(words)', 'from __main__ import reduced_set_calls_loop, words', number=number))
```

and the results:

```
Naive: 1.8516130640055053
Destructive: 0.3646556100138696
Reduced set calls: 0.5927464940032223
```

So moving the `set()` call in `reduced_set_calls_loop()` dramatically improves the first version already. Reducing the number of loops by replacing `if i < j` with a `for j in range(i):` loop further reduces the gap:

```
>>> def reduced_iteration_loop(words):
...     curr_max=0
...     for i in range(0,len(words)):
...         curr_word=set(words[i])
...         for j in range(i):
...             other_word=words[j]
...             for char in curr_word:
...                 if char in other_word:
...                     break
...             else:
...                 curr_max=max(curr_max,len(words[i])*len(other_word))
...     return curr_max
...
>>> print('Reduced iteration:', timeit('reduced_iteration_loop(words)', 'from __main__ import reduced_iteration_loop, words', number=number))
Reduced iteration: 0.44450017900089733
```

What I find surprising is that your destructive loop is faster than using `itertools.combinations()` however:

```
>>> from itertools import combinations
>>> def destructive_loop_empty(words):
...     while words:
...         curr_word, words = words[0], words[1:]
...         for word in words:
...             pass
...
>>> def empty_combinations(words):
...     for a, b in combinations(words, 2):
...         pass
...
>>> timeit('destructive_loop_empty(words[:])', 'from __main__ import destructive_loop_empty, words', number=1000)
0.324253979997593
>>> timeit('empty_combinations(words[:])', 'from __main__ import empty_combinations, words', number=1000)
0.5626872480061138
```

We could possible make your algorithm #2 faster by using [set disjunctions](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#set.isdisjoint), rather than test each character individually. Because we'll be testing words repeatedly, it makes sense to create the sets up-front, in a dictionary, acting as a cache we can draw from when testing.

Finally, we can make a non-destructive version by storing lengths in the dictionary too and just looping over the values (we destroy the dictionary instead):

```
def nondestructive_loop(words):
    curr_max = 0
    words = {w: (set(w), len(w)) for w in words}
    while words:
        curr_word, curr_word_length = words.popitem()[1]
        for other, other_length in words.values():
            if curr_word.isdisjoint(other):
                curr_max = max(curr_max, curr_word_length * other_length)
    return curr_max
```

This is the fastest I've been able to make this:

```
>>> print('Nondestructive:', timeit('nondestructive_loop(words)', 'from __main__ import nondestructive_loop, words', number=number))
Nondestructive: 0.2944725830020616
```

shaving off another 20%.

So, in conclusion, it is faster to iterate directly over a list, vs. generating indices from a `range()`, then indexing into the list. The difference is large enough that it is worth your while destroying the list (or dictionary)!

This is also what makes `itertools.combinations()` slower; it *has* to use indices, as it has to support combinations greater than 2 (which means you can't just delete from the input sequence).

Comment: Would it make sense to do `wordsets = dict(zip(words, map(set, words)))` and change the if-test to `if wordsets[a].isdisjoint(wordsets[b])`?

Comment: @StevenRumbalski: bingo, not even mapping `b` first already shaves of 66% of the time. Mapping `b` as well gives another couple of percentage points.

Comment: Yep.  I get Naive: 2.598675707337638, Destructive: 2.6030930600383297, 
Iterative: 2.04531153750888, 
Iterative with set: 0.6089805807696393.  I am surprised my Iterative does not get as much speedup on my system as yours.  I'm running Python 3.6.0 [MSC v.1900 32 bit (Intel)] on win32 on 64-bit Windows 7.  (I deploy to 32-bit Windows 7 users which is why I have 32 bit Python.)

Comment: I just realized that the above script is not using the correct algorithm for algorithm 2. I updated it and am again seeing the difference in timing I was finding earlier.

Comment: What happens when u change the loop of algorithm 1 like I did at the end of my edited OP, where the inner loop only goes from 0 to j instead of Len(words)? Shouldn't that solve doing way too many iterations?

Comment: @actuary_meets_data yes, that'll avoid all those extra steps. I don't know how fast it'll be; try it out, I'd say. I'm out of time for today; tomorrow perhaps.

Comment: I ran both your updated script and your updated script with the change mentioned in the last comment (inner loop goes from 0 to i instead of to len(words)), and there is no meaningful change in run-time. I really do not understand why there is such a significant difference in timing still between the two algorithms.

Comment: @actuary_meets_data: testing `for i in range(len(words)): for j in range(i): pass` shows that that part is about as fast as the `destructive_loop_empty()` version (both 0.34 seconds for 1000 repetitions).

Comment: @Martijn Pieters: Ah, I see what you mean about curr_word=set(words[i]) being in the incorrect place. I see a dramatic improvement after that change, but the destructive loop still seems to be about twice as fast on this type of input.

Comment: @actuary_meets_data: I've replaced my fastest version with a non-destructive variant; the dictionary that is created can hold the lengths too, and then you don't need the original list at all anymore. I find it fascinating that the `iterators.combinations()` version is slower too; it just goes to show that memory-saving iteration techniques are not necessarily faster!

Comment: Yeah, that's a good point. Very interesting overall to say the least! So any final theories on why we are observing this phenomenon?

Comment: @actuary_meets_data: looping directly over a list is faster than generating indices then indexing. And the difference is big enough to make it worth destroying the list (or dictionary) in the process!

Comment: would you argue that this is a python-specific attribute or programming-wide?

Comment: @actuary_meets_data: this is Python specific; the extra costs come from boxing and unboxing the integers between C code and Python. `range()` works with C integers, so you have to box them to a Python integer, then to use that integer to index into the list object, you need to unbox it again to get a C integer that can be used to index the C array.